# How do I remove dead links from the whisker search bar in xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xfce, menu, whisker

I have searched through the entire menu editor, deleting everything I do not want. However if I use the search feature in whisker the entries remain as dead links.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it by removing the links from

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
rm gog_com-Dragonsphere_1.desktop
rm unity-editor*
```

For some reason, I was given a prompt to remove these, but for some reason they persisted under multiple deletes. They were removed simply with sudo privileges.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question as solved.